# google plus open inside webview instead out of the wrapper

Tags: android, webview, google-plus

I have an android application with a webview. when clicking on external links like FB or Instagram - new chrome window open.when clicking on Google+ - the application opens inside the webview. I want to open the G+ out of the wrapper(achieved) but also to manage to redirect to a certain profile.
this is my code:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://plus.google.com/profile/posts")); 
 startActivity(intent);
```

The above code open G+ inside the wrapper which i don't want it to..

```
 PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
 Intent launchIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");
 if (launchIntent != null) {
 //intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.plus",
          //  "com.google.android.apps.plus.phone.UrlGatewayActivity");
 launchIntent.putExtra("customAppUri",profile);
 startActivity(launchIntent);}
```

The above code actually opens the G+ application out of the wrapper but it is not redirected to the profile page.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently G+ change their activity name to "com.google.android.libraries.social.gateway.GatewayActivity". updated accordingly and it works perfect!

the updated code:

```
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    Intent launchIntent = 
    pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");
    if (launchIntent != null) {
    intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.plus",
        "com.google.android.libraries.social.gateway.GatewayActivity");
    launchIntent.putExtra("customAppUri",profile);
    startActivity(launchIntent);}
```